# Can't install mercurial - python not found on mac disk

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, mercurial, interpreter

I've tried a couple different ways of installing mercurial.

1 - was using the package file from their website. I was unable to proceed, due to a "no Apple Python 2.7 found on Mac Disk" error.

2 - brew install mercurial works, however running hg --version returns this error

```
/usr/local/bin/hg: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Of course I'm thinking there's something wrong with the paths. I've tried to create a symlink but I've had no success - the problem remains. Out of interest, I tried to see if I could even find Python 2.7 on my system.

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
ls
Documentation  Headers  Resources  module.map  
Examples  Python  Versions  
cd Python
cd: python: No such file or directory
```

**If I ls under versions, I only get 2.3, 2.5 and 2.6. 2.7 is gone.**

It's confusing.. because it's clearly there, but the directory is not there. I'm worried something has gone totally astray (perhaps I deleted the default python shipped with OSX? Ouch)

This is what my .bash_profile looks like

```
# Setting PATH For Python 2.7
PATH = "/usr/local/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#Setting PATH for Python 3.2
PATH ="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#Setting PATH for Python 3.4
PATH = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you run `python` from Terminal? Or it gives you error as well?

Comment: I can run python from the terminal - it runs in 2.7.10

Comment: so run `which python`, edit the PATH and `sudo pip install mercurial`

Comment: If I run which python I get /usr/local/bin/python - is this supposed to be the correct location for Python?

Comment: If this is the correct Python interpreter (the one you wanna install mercurial for), then yes.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using? Did you, by any chance, upgrade to El Capitan (which changed a few things)?

Comment: I'm confused @ForceBru - My bash_profile looks like the one in the post. Is it not correct already? If it's not, what should I change and what to?